# About lambda syntax

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I was examining JDK 8 APIs and inside `Function` interface I noticed identity function

```
static <T> Function<T, T> identity() {
    return t -> t;
}
```

This resolves to method:

```
R apply(T t);
```

declared in the same `Function` interface.

Question is why `t -> t` part works.

If we expand this expression in terms of familiar *Anonymous Inner Class*

```
new Function<String, String>() {

    @Override
    String apply(String t) {
         t; // Oops, compilation error
    }
}
```

Is `t -> t` kind of shortcut of `t -> { return t; }`?

Comment: That's just part of the lambda syntax, and yes, `t -> t` is just shortcut syntax for `t -> { return t; }`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Question is why `t -> t` part works.

Because a lambda expression can return the value it takes as parameter. The `return` is implied in the right part from the target type of the lambda expression. The expression is essentially same as:

```
t -> { return t; }
```

That means that `t -> t` would fail for a functional interface with method that has `void` return type, as in below case:

```
Consumer<String> consumer = t -> t;
```

The target type of lambda there is [`Consumer<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html), which has the method - `void accept(T t)` in it. Since the method has `void` return type, the above assignment fails.

You can go through [State of the Lambda](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-state-final.html) for more insight.